# 360 degree view field

Tags: opencv, camera, opencv-stitching

I am in an FRC team, and thinking out of the box with uber-powerful image processing being used, I want to know a couple cameras that are 90-120 degrees so I can put 3-4 and stitch the images together to get an excessively large image to get all 8 targets with. I would like to essentially design a GPS system that will work even if one side of the robot is being blocked!

I have OpenCV available, as well as NI Vision.

Comment: What is the real question!

Comment: i don't understand the question - do you need camera suggestions that work with OpenCV and have a high field-of-view?

Comment: Yes. I need to get a camera with an extremely large field of view!

Answer (score 0):

you can use fish eye lens to increase the field of view alternatively you can use array of cameras and stitch each frames from array of cameras to create 360 view.
i.e. http://shop.360heros.com/category-s/1817.htm